# In spring MVC controller change file write path

Tags: spring-mvc

I write code to create automatically file in my work directory.

The path is working but I have given full system path, Now I want to create the file in my resources folder without  `E:\\Hello\\`

Now the path is,

```
E:\\Hello\\file.txt
```

I want

```
resources/file.txt
```

My controller

```
String message= "Hello World";
try {
    Files.write(Paths.get("E:\\Hello\\Hello\\file.txt"), message, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My stack trace

```
May 14, 2018 6:39:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SpringDispatcher] in context with path [/Hello] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liteOn.controller.HomeController.tmax(HomeController.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code created the `file.txt` in my resources folder. Then the tomcat folder checked my project folder `Hello`, In that project folder Inside that resources folder `file.txt` has been created.

```
String message= "Hello World";

String realPath  = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/resources/file.txt");

Files.write(Paths.get(realPath), message, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
String fileName = "static/java.ini"; 
Files.write(Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).toString()), data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

You will get the path of the your Spring Application root directory.

**UPDATE**

To access the file generated using the above method, try the following code:

```
@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl {

    public String reader(String fileName) {
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).toURI());
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path);
            lines.forEach((String line) -> data.append(line).append("\n"));
            lines.close();

            path = null;
            return data.toString();

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is not working, Not showing the created file and I searched all my working directory

Comment: it will create a file inside `target` directory not in your project directory.

Comment: How can i access again the same File, To get data

Comment: In the target directory not showing file, It showing some error.                     SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SpringDispatcher] in context with path [/app] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

Comment: post the stacktrace to your question

Comment: Yeah ok, I posted my stack trace

Comment: was your class annotated with `@Controller` or `@Service` ?

Comment: With @Controller

Comment: create a `service` class and paste those code in that class and then autowire when you use it in your `controller`. It should work as i am using it in my `spring boot` project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171047/discussion-between-ashok-charu-and-sam).